# Dereference Field Name in Java to Validate it

Tags: java, spring

In `PHP`, which is, of course, an interpreted language, I can dereference field names at runtime, e.g. `'source'` and `'value'` below, and use the values of those two fields pointed to by source and value.

```
{$key['source']}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

Is there a similar facility in `Java` to do so?  I have some properties of a bean that I need to validate and perform various checks against.  Rather than hardcoding the logic, I'd like to loop through a `SQL` table of fieldnames and perform the indicated validation on the field.  E.g. if I have the value `"email"` in the database, I would pick the property below and validate it based on the rules in the database column:

```
String email;
```

I will have many beans and many fields, which is why I was thinking of this approach.  I don't have a say in the design  :(

Another option I was thinking was using `Spring validation`, but there does not appear to be a way to trigger it until a `Spring Form Bean` is submitted.  Maybe there's an alternate way to trigger it?

Comment: please, consider to revisit a little your question because for me it's not too clear. If I understood you need to check about some fields without knowing their names from the database? In that case you can get the column list from the db and you have the value that you need. Put them in something like an Hashtable and you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the option to change them from scalars to a bunch of fields in a Collection.  Trust me, if it were that easy, I would have done so.

Comment: so, I cannot understand your question. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are saying that you wish to store the names of properties in a data store, and access that data store at runtime to query the properties. The construct you have described is closest to a Map in Java - a key/value pair, and there is nothing to stop you accessing data stored that way, e.g. `myMap.get("myproperty");`. The problem is modelling all your Objects as Maps isn't very OO.

Another option is to use reflection and convention. So a property in your database named 'source' would be accessed by a method called 'getSource()'. This is similar to JavaBeans

Is that what you meant?